# Storing the transaction done by paypal sandbox add to cart button

Tags: jakarta-ee, paypal, payment-processing, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal sandbox **add to cart** button, it is working fine but i want to save the transactions done by that button, that is i want to save customer id, no of items sold and their prices etc, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd advise you to expand your question just a bit. Is this server side code? Direct postback to PayPal's NVP API?

Answer (score 0):

Use PayPal IPN; https://www.paypal.com/ipn/ - PayPal will then initiate a POST to a script on your server, which will contain all information about the transaction. The item ordered, the amount it was ordered for, the first name of the buyer, the last name of the buyer, et cetera.

Comment: Any particular reason this was downvoted? Considering this is exactly what you need to use.